# TableSorter sorting empty input in Td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tablesorter

I'm testing tablesorter and my table is :

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HjfOU.png)

It contains list of products and one product has 2 rows, one row contains its name and the other is the input field for the user to make changes.

I would like to do a tablesorter to sort the products with the empty input fields to the top of the table.

[Table Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bOLp.png)

It means the products which don't have text in the input fields will be displayed on top.

I'm using tablesorter jquery.

my HTML Table: Tr1 holds first 'data' line, TR2 holds the input fields;

```
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="sorter-inputs empty-top code">Code</th>
            <th class="sorter-inputs empty-top designation">Designation</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class='tr1'>
            <td>
                <div class='code'>&nbsp;</div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class='designation'>abc 111</div>
            </td>
        </tr>       

        <tr class='tr2'>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class='CodeInput'/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class='designationInput'/>
            </td>
        </tr>

    ...
    </tbody> </table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using my [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), you have two options.

1) Leave out the input rows and use the [editable widget](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-editable.html), which actually makes the table cell editable using `contenteditable`. This does require a modern browser.

2) Use the input parser & set the `emptyTo` option to keep empty rows at the top ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/856bzzeL/207/))

*NOTE*: the `parser-input-select.js` file used in the demo is actually pointing to the master branch of the repository.

HTML

```
<table class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="sorter-inputs empty-top code">Code</th>
            <th class="sorter-inputs empty-top designation">Designation</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <div>abc 111</div>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

* Note *: I don't think using child rows will work in this case because the sort would occur based on the parent row content. So I added a `<div>` to each cell with the labels.

CSS

```
html { box-sizing: border-box; }
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }
.code { width: 20%; }
.designation { width: 80%; }
input { width: 90%; margin: 4px; background: #fc7565; border: solid 1px #999; }
table { border-collapse: collapsed; border-spacing: 0; }
.tablesorter-blue tbody td { padding: 0; vertical-align: bottom; }
td div { background: #ccc; padding: 4px; }
```

Script

```
$(function () {
    $('table').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue'
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your good reply, I tried the example you guided me above, however, my html structure is a bit different as there is 2 TRs which hold data for one specific product, so if i do the sort, all the text will be set all above the input fields, could you please check again my above post, i have updated the html code, Thanks

Comment: Ok, so essentially you don't want any of the content in the `tr1` rows sortable, just the input values in `tr2`, with empty values sorted first?

Comment: In fact, i want to sort tr2 with empty field along with tr1 because each tr1 and tr2 belong to one product. So those with empty fields in tr2 will be sorted on top, along with its tr1, my apology if it is confusing thanks @Mottie